# Transform specific text (identified based on pattern) to a link with Javascript

Tags: javascript

The following code I have is looking for a specific text in the DOM, based on a pattern.
Instead of replacing the text I would like to transform it to a link where the text is a parameter in the link.

Let's say the link would look like: https://google.com/search?q=matched_text_added_here

```
var allTextNodes = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT),
    // some temp references for performance
    tmptxt,
    tmpnode,
    // compile the RE and cache the replace string, for performance
    identify = /ABC\d{7}/g,
    replaceValue = "changed";

// iterate through all text nodes
while (allTextNodes.nextNode()) {
    tmpnode = allTextNodes.currentNode;
    tmptxt = tmpnode.nodeValue;
    tmpnode.nodeValue = tmptxt.replace(identify, replaceValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Instead of replacing the text I would like to transform it to a link

So, instead of replacing the text:

1. create a link

```js
let newLink = document.createElement('a')
```

2. configure the link

```js
newLink.href = 'https://google.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(nodeValue)
newLink.textContent = nodeValue
```

3. replace the text node with the link node

```js
tmpnode.replaceWith(newLink)
```